# Converting Timezone String to UTC offset using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have a Wordpress marketplace store where the "author" of a product has their timezone stored in usermeta in the string format, i.e. `Americas/Chicago`.

I am wanting to output each user's timezone with a UTC offset instead of string so I can more easily manipulate it.  I got this example below from another stack overflow question but it isn't working in my situation.

```
$timezone = 'America/New_York'; //example string although I am getting the timezone from the database based on each users settings

if(!empty($timezone)) {
    $UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
    $newTZ = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    $date = new DateTime( $newTZ );
    $date->setTimezone( $UTC);
    echo $date->format('H:i:s');
}
```

However, this code breaks the page.  Can't understand why it would be breaking the page.  I put it into a separate function and it still breaks and the error log isn't much help either.

The log says:

```
DateTime->__construct(Object(DateTimeZone))
```

Comment: It's kind of a bad idea to use offsets! Can you not solve your problem with the DateTimeZone object instead?

Comment: @Evert Hey, I can use all the feedback I can get.  The bottom line is, I have these course times in different timezones and I am going to need to translate them based on the current browser's timezone.  UTC seems to be the best option for this?  Am I wrong?  Thx for the input.

Comment: Converting to UTC might cause some future dates to incorrect. The two major things that impact this is twice-yearly DST changes and changes to the timezone database. If you are doing things with the frontend (in javascript) take a look at the Moment.js package. It supports the same timezone strings.

Comment: Please read "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

The timezone is *second* parameter for `DateTime`. So if you want to work with "now' either pass "now" or `null` as the first parameter.

```
$timezone = 'America/New_York'; //example string although I am getting the timezone from the database based on each users settings

if(!empty($timezone)) {
    $UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
    $newTZ = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    $date = new DateTime(null, $newTZ );
    $date->setTimezone( $UTC);
    echo $date->format('H:i:s');
}
```